# how to use travis and octopress to auto deploy blog

Tags: rubygems, rake, jekyll, octopress

Let me first declare that I'm not an expert on ruby or octopress. I am trying to use travis
(https://travis-ci.org/ ) to auto deploy my octopress blog hosted on github. the ***.travis.yml*** file which octopress creates by default has this command

```
bundle exec rake install
```

the build is failing because this command waits for user input as it tries to replace my custom theme by default octopress classic theme. So how and where do I need to configure so that It accepts my custom theme fyn and don't complain.

I'm getting this error message:

```
A theme is already installed, proceeding will overwrite existing files. Are you sure? [y/n] n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the line you need to edit is right [here](https://github.com/imathis/octopress/blob/master/Rakefile#L34) (line 34) in the current Octopress `Rakefile`. By removing that `if` statement it will not ask about overwriting the theme.

Comment: Hi, thanks I figured out that the command was redundant even though generated as default by octopress. simply using rake generate and rake deploy serves the purpose.